# BSPWM creates false desktop when using multiple displays

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, arch-linux, xorg, window-manager

I am currently trying to configure BSPWM for 2 of 3 displays in my system. I have two 1080p monitors. The left is rotated 90degrees to be vertical, and the right is typical 16:9. I also have a third display connected however it is disabled. I have configured my displays using arandr as such:

```
#########
#       #  ################
#       #  #              #
# 9:16  #  #     16:9     #
#       #  #              #
#       #  ################
#       #
#########
```

However bspwm seems to place a third desktop in-between the two, which I have not specified. As shown:

```
#########
#   @@@@@@@@@@@@@##########
#   @           @         #
#   @@@@@@@@@@@@@         #
#       #  #              #
#       #  ################
#       #
#########
```

Whenever I try to move applications over to my left monitor, they often appear in this strange 3rd desktop. I've tried many solutions to remove it, however I am unable to figure this issue out.

Here's my Display configuration:

```
xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output DP-1 --off --output HDMI-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1080x198 --rotate normal --output DP-2 --off
```

My BSPWM config:

```
#! /bin/sh
pgrep -x sxhkd > /dev/null || sxhkd &
$HOME/.config/polybar/launch.sh


# Disabled
#bspc monitor DP-2 -d A B C D E
# Right Display
bspc monitor HDMI-0 -d I II III IV V
# Left Vert Display
bspc monitor DP-0 -d 1 2 3 4 5


bspc config border_width         2
bspc config window_gap          13

bspc config split_ratio          0.5
bspc config borderless_monocle   true
bspc config gapless_monocle      true

exec ~/.screenlayout/default.sh &
feh --bg-fill ~/Pictures/forrest.png &
```

This issue has been puzzling me for a while now, and I would love some assistance. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean b  it's disabled?  Clearly, it is not.  Just disconnect it.  If that's not a solution then you haven't explained what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am unable to disconnect DP-2 as it is part of my laptop which I have docked. My only solution is to disable it. As for the issue which I am trying to address, I'd like to get rid of the third desktop which seems to have appeared in-between my 2 displays.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. kinda solved this by removing 3rd desktop like this:

```
$ bspc query -M --names
$ bspc monitor DP-1-1 --remove
```

Removing the monitor can leave some unmanaged windows without parent desktop it seems, so I have to be really careful to no have any desktops with windows there.

Comment: What also helped was defining the main display in my bspwmrc: `bspc monitor <main-display-name> -d 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`